# MSSQL to MYSQL - Select from MSSQL , Insert into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im trying to Establish a One Direction Sync from a specific query'd recordset from MSSQL (express 2008) to Mysql. Here is that query.

```
SELECT [datafk]
  ,[datahistorypk]
  ,[date]
  ,[displayText]
FROM [FCentral].[dbo].[DataHistory]

WHERE [sampleNr] = 
    (SELECT MAX (sampleNr) FROM [FCentral].[dbo].[DataHistory])
```

This results in a Multiple results. I need to insert each of those results into my "Linked Server" remotely connected MySQL DB Table.

This code works from SSMS and does insert into my MySQL DB.

```
EXEC (' INSERT INTO  `farms`.`CCData` (
       `datafk` ,`datahistorypk` ,`date` ,`displayText` )
      VALUES ("222",  "13",  "2017-10-19 14:25:05",  "TEST"); ')
at BPF_REMOTE
```

Ultimately i will need to schedule this query to run automatically, It would be nice if it could run if a change was detected in the MSSQL table but that may be outside of my abilities.

I feel like im close, im just struggling to get the syntax right to convert from MSSQL to MySQL. Can anyone either point to a good example or help me with this query?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine) in SQL Server and just do a regular insert:

```
INSERT INTO BPF_REMOTE.farms.CCData(datafk, datahistorypk, date, displayText)
    SELECT [datafk], [datahistorypk], [date], [displayText]
    FROM [FCentral].[dbo].[DataHistory]
    WHERE [sampleNr] = (SELECT MAX (sampleNr) FROM [FCentral].[dbo].[DataHistory]);
```

Comment: Invalid object name 'BPF_REMOTE.farms.CCData'.

Do I need to do something special to setup the LinkedServer DB as an Object?

Comment: @TrippWilliamson . . . Yes.  Follow the instructions in the link.

Comment: I followed another set of instructions and used SSMS to setup the link, I dont really see differences in how the  sp_addlinkedserver works vs SSMS.
----
I more or less did this "You can also define linked servers by using SQL Server Management Studio. In the Object Explorer, right-click Server Objects, select New, and select Linked Server. "
----- This was the guide i followed. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4570/access-mysql-data-from-sql-server-via-a-linked-server/

Comment: I believe i need to convert your query to use openquery to make this work.